# Как найти все простые числа, произведение которых дает число 100?

Tags: java

Собственно пытаюсь решить такую задачу. Логику придумал такую. Сначала создаю цикл от 2 до 100, чтобы найти все простые числа в этом диапазоне. А вот что делать дальше не могу понять. Как можно найти числа произведение которых дает число 100?

Код на JAVA:

```
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= 100; j++) {
            boolean simple = false;

            for (int i = 2; i * i <= j; i++) {
                simple = (j % i == 0);
                if (simple) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!simple) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `100 = 2*2*5*5`. Ключевое слово - "факторизация".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не обязательно искать простые числа, они сами найдутся, если будете проверять делимость целевого числа на множители, и делить, пока возможно, чтобы учесть кратность.

Примерно так:

```
int n = 100;
int step = 1;
for (int i = 2; n > 1; i+=step) {
    while (n%i== 0) {
       n /= i;
       System.out.print(i);
   }
   if (i == 3)
      step = 2;
}
```